# How to decode call metadata token in CIL?

Tags: .net, assembly, .net-assembly, bytecode, cil

I was looking into CIL assembly and I don't understand how to decode the metadata token from the call instuction. From ECMA-335 documentation:

> The call instruction calls the method indicated by the descriptor method. method is a metadata
>   token (a methodref, methoddef, or methodspec;)

I can't find any reference to this token encoding. Thank you.

Comment: The high order byte indicates the token type/table index (eg 0x06 indicates a MethodDef token), the remaining 3 bytes indicate the row index within the table. This is mentioned in ECMA-335 Partition II section 22 (shortly before section 22.1).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Module.ResolveMethod Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.reflection.module.resolvemethod(v=vs.110).aspx) to get a `MethodInfo` object from a metadata token.

> Returns the method identified by a metadata token.

Have a look at the different overload-pages in the msdn, they contain a quite extensive example.